# How does a Python reduce XORing two indices on a lambda variable work?

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce

```
# Compute the XOR of all numbers from 0 to |A| - 1 and all entries in A
# Assume A is a list of integers
miss_XOR_dup = functools.reduce(lambda v, i: v ^ i[0] ^ i[1], enumerate(A), 0)
```

I believe that the value the function begins accumulating at is 0 and that *v* and *i* are the index of and element value of the items in array *A*. However, it's a bit confusing that *v* doesn't stand for "value" but rather "index" and vice versa for *i*. This also contradicts that the code `i[0]` is possible because you can't select an index from an integer.

If someone could expand the reduce into a for loop or better explain how this code fulfills the comment above it, I would be very appreciative.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) `calculates
`((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`,

Comment: Note that xor is commutative and associative: `A ^ B` = `B ^ A` and `(A ^ B) ^ C` = `A ^ (B ^ C)`. So it doesn't matter what order these are done with, as long as they are done on all the inputs. (But you're correct, `v` is the index and `i` is the element.)

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems. Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details. This question doesn't follow [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) gidelines. There's a high chance that the question will be closed as "too broad'..

Comment: @torek No, `v` isn't the index and `i` isn't the element (unless with "element" you do mean an index+element tuple).

Comment: @StefanPochmann: oops, right, I was looking at the wrong part when I wrote that. `v` is the value-so-far, as you noted in your answer.

Comment: I updated the code with a comment describing what A is and edited the title a bit. Since this isn't really a software bug but rather a question about how functional code works logically, I can't really post what I've tried so far. Anything else you would change, @CristiFati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With descriptive variable names...

```
reduce(lambda xorSoFar, nextIndexAndValue:
              xorSoFar ^ nextIndexAndValue[0] ^ nextIndexAndValue[1],
       enumerate(values),
       0)
```

Comment: I guess the downvote means that when the problem is a misunderstanding of what the variables hold, telling them what the variables hold is bad?

Comment: I thought this was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`v` is the last value returned by `lambda` (or `0` on the first call), `i` is a tuple `(<index of item in A>, <item in A>)`. These tuples are produced by `enumerate`.